# Помогите, пожалуйста, с позиционированием в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-grid

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при изменении размера окна текст всегда был в центре картинки, как это можно сделать?

Код программы:

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
            <StackPanel.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Resources/bg_ventilation.jpg" Stretch="Uniform"/>
            </StackPanel.Background>
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=SPTextBlock}" Text="Введите данные" FontSize="22"/>
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=SPTextBlock}" Text="И программа выполнит расчеты" FontSize="14"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>

//Код стиля в App.xaml
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="SPTextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `<StackPanel Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center">` а обои на `Grid` перевесить.

Comment: Во-первых, не "Нужно" а "Необходимо". "Нужно" это требование, что отторгает от помощи.

Во-вторых, у вас фото в режиме Uniform, то есть оно будет подстраиваться своим бОльшим размером в окно. Если же вы сожмёте фото по высоте то у вас всё равно текст выйдет за фото, ведь обои будут очень маленькими. Лучше использовать UniformToFill. Либо сделайте размер окна фиксированным, запретив изменение размера свойством ResizeMode="None"